# Sending requests to a spring servers without waiting for a response

Tags: spring, rest, asynchronous, service, resttemplate

I am writing two services that do some calculations. One of them must only send a lot of requests to second service without waiting for a response:

```
...
for (String url: oneService.getUrlList()) {
    try {
       sendRequests(restTemplate, url);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
...

@Async
void sendRequests(RestTemplate restTemplate, String url) throws InterruptedException {
   restTemplate.postForLocation("http://second-servive/calculation/" + url, String.class);
}
```

I have in controller of second service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "calculation/{url}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getShortCircuitCalculation(@PathVariable String url) {
     secondService.getCalculation(url);
}
```

I created many instances of the second service with eureka server to make calculations faster. But with **@Async** annotation and instances of second service it takes a lot of time, just like with a single instance. The first service is still waiting for responses from the second service. I tried to send responses in separate threads, but got the same.

Are there any ways to not wait for the response from the second service and continue sending responses so instances make calculations?

Comment: The `@Async` is useless as it is an internal method call. Spring AOP uses proxy based app and as such it will only work for external method calls. So basically you don't have anything async in there.

Comment: In addition to bypassing the AOP - do you have the @EnableAsync in place somewhere?

Comment: C. Weber, Yes before declaring a class with "sendRequests" method.